# Как в Blender вытянуть стенки ровно под уровень горизонта?

Tags: blender

Делаю в Blender площадку с уклоном в землю, и надо вытянуть стенки по бокам ровно под уровень горизонта. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Делается очень просто. Нажимаете <kbd>S</kbd> (масштабирование), Затем выбираете ось, для горизонта, я полагаю нужна ось <kbd>Z</kbd> (ось так-же можно выбирать средней кнопкой мыши), затем жмете <kbd>0</kbd>, чтобы указать, что вы хотите отмасштабировать на 0. Итак получается все точки выровнены по оси Z.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]